# NavigationLink causing ChildView to reinitialize whenever ParentView is visible again (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I currently have an app where the user goes through pages of lists to make multiple selections from. (using NavigationLinks)

**PROBLEM:**    The functionality is fine if the user simply makes their selection then moves on, however the issue is when the user goes back THEN forward to a page. I.e. ViewA -> ViewB -> View->A -> ViewB.
Doing this causes ViewB to reinitialize and delete all previous selections on that page, even if ViewA didn't update.
Note that using the back button preserves selections as expected.

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:**
I want to preserve states through navigation of these pages.

**ViewA:**

```
struct YouthEventCheckInView: View {

@StateObject var trackable = TrackableMetricsManager(metricType: TrackableMetricType.Event, isCheckin: true)
@StateObject var event = CustomMetricManager()
@StateObject var checkInViewModel = CheckInViewModel()

@State private var moveToDailyStressorsView = false
@State private var newEvent = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: YouthStressorCheckInView(checkInViewModel: checkInViewModel), isActive: $moveToDailyStressorsView) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                    Button {
                        moveToDailyStressorsView = true
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Next")
                    }
        .navigationTitle("Major Life Events")
        .onAppear {
            trackable.observeEvents()
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewB (ViewC is same setup as this one):**

```
struct YouthStressorCheckInView: View {
@StateObject var trackable = TrackableMetricsManager(metricType: TrackableMetricType.Stressor, isCheckin: true)
@StateObject var stressor = CustomMetricManager()

@ObservedObject var checkInViewModel: CheckInViewModel

@State private var moveToCopingStrategiesView = false
@State private var newStressor = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack {

        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                NavigationLink(destination: YouthStrategyCheckInView(checkInViewModel: checkInViewModel), isActive: $moveToCopingStrategiesView) {
                    EmptyView()
                }

                Button( action: {
                    moveToCopingStrategiesView = true
                }, label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Next")
                })
            }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Daily Stressors")
    .onAppear {
        trackable.observeStressors()
    }
}
```

**ViewModel for these views:**

```
class ViewCheckInViewModel: ObservableObject {
struct Item: Hashable {
    let name: String
    let color: String
    let image: String
}

@Published var loading = false
@Published var majorLifeEvents: [Item] = []
@Published var dailyStressors: [Item] = []
@Published var copingStrategies: [Item] = []
@Published var date: String = ""


func loadData(withDataStore dataStore: AWSAppSyncDataStore, checkInId: String) {
    self.checkInId = checkInId
    loadDate(withDataStore: dataStore)
    loadMajorLifeEvents(withDataStore: dataStore)
    loadDailyStressors(withDataStore: dataStore)
    loadCopingStrategies(withDataStore: dataStore)
}

private func loadMajorLifeEvents(withDataStore dataStore: AWSAppSyncDataStore) {
    ...
}

private func loadDailyStressors(withDataStore dataStore: AWSAppSyncDataStore) {
    ...
}

private func loadCopingStrategies(withDataStore dataStore: AWSAppSyncDataStore) {
    ...
}
```

NOTE: Obviously some code is taken out, I left the things that I thought were necessary for this issue

Comment: If you want to preserve states then keep them inside view models outside of view, so being injected in view (independently of creation/re-creation) the state is restored from view model.

Comment: @Asperi thanks, so you're saying each page I should have an individual ViewModel? Because they all run off of 1 ViewModel currently.